# Creating a PHP Template with Objects

Tags: php, oop, templates

I'm attempting to create a php template that includes object oriented code. Here's a simplified example of what I am trying to do.

*index.php*

```
<?php  require 'requiredfile.php'; ?>

    <html>
      <body>
         <h1><?php echo $object1->variable ?></h1>
      </body>
    </html>
```

But what if I wanted to use the same template for multiple objects? I definitely don't want to have to create different versions of index.php for objects 1, 2 and 3.  I'm assuming I could do something like `$this->variable` and pass in the object, but I'm not entirely sure how to do that since it's outside the declaration of that class.

Comment: Where is the object instantiated? Why can't you instantiate as many as you need?

$object1= new myClass; 
$object2= new myClass;

Comment: the object is instantiated in requiredfile.php. i wanted to separate that logic from the presentation/template.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a nice trick to do what you want. Invert the logic and have the class call the template:

```
class MyClass {
  //
  // add whatever properties you like here
  //
  public function Render(){ 
    include ( 'mytemplate.php' );
  }
}
```

Now, inside the file `mytemplate.php` you can call any property or method of the class by simply using `$this->whatever`.

This pattern is easily reusable with different objects:

```
$x = new MyClass;
$x->Render();

$y = new MyClass;
$y->Render();
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to access variables like this?
say you have 2 pages Home and About

```
 //requiredfile.php
        Class PageFromTemplate{
            function __construct($title,$type){
            $this->type = $type;
                  $this->_setTitle($title);
            }

            private function _setTitle($title){
                  $this->title = $title;
            }


            }.

        //index.php


        <?php  require 'requiredfile.php'; 

        $home =  new PageFromTemplate("myHomeTitle","Home");

        ?>

            <html>
              <body>
                 <h1><?php echo "this page is of type : " . $home->type; ?></h1>
              </body>
            </html>
```

do the same on about page as well,

```
$about = new PageFromTemplate("myAboutTitle","About");`
```